# Using a wildcard on S3 Event Notification prefix

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a Lambda function that creates a thumbnail image for every image that gets uploaded to my bucket, it then places the Thumbnail inside another bucket.  When I upload a user image (profile pic) I use the users **ID** and **name** as part of the key:

`System-images/users/250/john_doe.jpg`

Is there a way to use a wildcard in the `prefix` path?  This is what I have so far but it doesn't work

[image: S3 bucket properties]

Comment: Astonishing this still isn't supported.

Comment: I can't believe this is not supported...

Comment: Here's why: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-event-notification-filter-wildcard/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, you can't -- it's a literal *prefix*.

In your example, you could use either of these prefixes, depending on what else is in the bucket (if there are things sharing the common prefix that you don't want to match):

```
System-images/
System-images/users/
```

Comment: You're correct, I ended up using suffix instead and creating many event notifications for `jpg`, `png` and `jpeg`.  The lambda function will only fire for these file types.

Answer (score 6):

Wildcards in prefix/suffix filters of Lambda are not supported and will never be since the asterisk (*) is a valid character that can be used in S3 object key names. However, you could somehow fix this problem by adding a filter in your Lambda function. For example:

First, get the source key:

```
var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

Then, check if it is inside the `users` folder:

```
if (srcKey.indexOf('/users/') === -1) {
    callback('Not inside users folder!');
    return;
}
```

Comment: My use case for wildcards is because our folder structure is `1/<country>/users/name/<filename>.json`. Countries will expand over time, so I can't possibly list down all the countries, it's not scalable. Currently, I am using your solution, but this causes too many unnecessary, triggers to the lambda as within the users and name folder, there are other .json files as well which I don't care of. Thinking of a SNS, but might be a tad overkill.

Comment: @ChickenWing24 if this is still a problem for you, one possible workaround for that  specific folder structure is to use a suffix notification and use temporary <filename>.json that will trigger the event. Obviously, it's not ideal but it might be what you're interested in.

Write your file to 1/<country>/users/name/<filename>.tmp-s3-suffix-uuid1.json and then your s3 notification would need to filter on the suffix ".tmp-s3-suffix-uuid1.json" and your function would need to move the file to <filename>.json after processing.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. Thanks @AidanHoolachan. I'm no longer working on the project, but will pass this to my colleagues.

Comment: This solution would still hurt, if I end up invoking this lambda(even if just checking the object key) for millions of file which I could ignore with the regex itself. I believe S3 trigger should support other means to use wild cards even if not this format, as they have limitations.