# AWS Lambda function with varying prefix

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to configure an AWS lambda function that, when the trigger occurs, performs actions like appending additional data to a report and renaming files among other actions. This post is not for how to write the code for these actions, rather, I am seeking advice for how to handle the varying prefix where the report lives.

The final report lives in an AWS bucket-prefix structure as follows:

`s3://marvel-analysis/mcu/dx-hero-230211/marvel_report.csv`

The aforementioned actions will be performed on file `marvel_report.csv`, but I am hung up on the fact that the prefix that this file lives in will change with each analysis performed. Everything in the AWS URI above will remain constant except for prefix `dx-hero-230211` because we could have analyses done on "villains" and the date will change with each incoming analysis (ex. the prefix for a later run is `dx-villain-230223`). My initial thought was to experiment with configuring the test event using the "S3 Put" template. But I cannot seem to correctly handle the varying prefix.

Here is what my current test event looks like:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "Global",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "marvel-analysis",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::marvel-analysis"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "mcu/dx-hero-230211/marvel_report.csv",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to "wildcard" the key to something like `"mcu/{dx-hero/villain-YYMMDD}/marvel_report.csv"`

If it helps, I am able to extract this prefix with the following, but only if hardcoded:

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import os

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    run_id = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].split("/")[1]
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        print(run_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

I'm new to AWS lambda functions and how S3 works. I appreciate any advice or learning opportunities that might help me with this.

Comment: Could you simply trigger on a suffix of `marvel_report.csv` or on a combined prefix of `mcu/` plus suffix of `/marvel_report.csv`? See [filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-how-to-filtering.html).

Comment: You can't set a filter on anything except a simple prefix match.  If you want to filter further, you can do so in the Lambda with something like `if not re.match("mcu/dx-(hero|villain)-\\d{6}/", event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']): return`

Comment: @jarmod - the trigger is actually what you said; once ```marvel_report.csv``` gets put into ```s3://marvel-analysis/mcu/dx-hero-230211/```, the function will perform the actions I mentioned. My issue is that object/prefix it resides in ```dx-hero-230211``` will change every time a new workflow is ready.

Comment: Right, but you simply parse that from the key in the event (as you're doing). There is [no support for wildcards](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-event-notification-filter-wildcard) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107809/using-a-wildcard-on-s3-event-notification-prefix)).